# Should installing local Drush and Drupal via Composer on my personal computer be any different than on hosting platform?

Tags: installation

Should installing local Drush and corresponding Drupal via Composer on a personal computer with Ubuntu-Apache-MySQL-PHP be any different than on a shared hosting platform?

Should I just do the following in **both** environments?

```
cd web_application_root
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project my_site_name_dir
# PHP MYADMIN GUI
# GUI install
composer require drupal/metatag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

When installing drupal and drush with composer, you can do it the same way on a shared hosting platform as you do locally-- assuming the shared hosting platform gives you access to the same command-line tools that you have available locally.

**Long answer: Use version control**

Generally speaking, you want to use composer with git, and you will check in your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files into the git repo.  You would then clone that repo to your local environment + your shared hosting environment.

This way, although you have multiple copies of `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, they are all managed via the git repo, so it is much easier to sync changes between your local environment and the shared hosting server.

Comment: Thank you, and I appreciate the "generally speaking" as Git might be an overkill for me because I aim to create just one Drupal website, for myself (no team members), for my personal services, only core with Metatag module, only text, updated directly online.

Comment: Not using version control is a huge mistake no matter how few people will be touching it. It is never overkill. Do yourself a favor and use it.

Comment: @drupal_love I develop everything by myself, but I do use git on all my projects now.  It really comes in handy when you need to do a rollback because something goes wrong with a major upgrade (such as the coming Drupal 10 upgrade this year).  When you're comfortable with version control, it can be set up in less than five minutes-- in my case, it's `git init` the repo and copy my SSH public key file to shared hosting-- so it's really not huge additional overhead.